# Trying to do smooth scrolling but a error in JS shows up

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I have no idea how to programme in JS, but I wanted to make a smooth scrolling animation when pressing the "Trailer" button, but there is some kind of error that says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

```js
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.titulo { 
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00000;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="titulo"><a class="titulo" href="#trailer">TRAILER</a></li>
</ul>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
 
 <div id="trailer">
    <h1>TRAILER</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Add jquery in your code

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: you need to add the jQuery in your code read this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Thank you for that one as well!

Answer (score 1):

You should include jQuery library in your project.

Just put this tag inside the `<head></head>` section of your html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that one!

Answer (score 0):

If you included jQuery already (see the other comments), it could also be the case that you enabled the no-conflict mode of jQuery. Then you need to use "jQuery" instead of "$".